# How to create a loop to go through a list of URLs, scrape all data. all URLs of the similar pages are saved in one file.txt (every URL in one line)?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to extract some information from multiple pages which have similar page structures.
all URLs of the pages are saved in one file.txt (every URL in one line).
I already create the code to scrape all the data from one link (it works).

### But I don't know how I create a loop to go through all the list of URLs from the txt file, and scrape all the data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from bs4 import Comment
import re

import rispy # Writing an ris file

with open('F:\Python\Python-FilePy-Thesis-DownLoad/Thesis2.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        url = line.strip()

html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

Comment: I think you can use:
`with open(r'F:\Python\Python-FilePy-Thesis-DownLoad/Thesis2.txt', 'r') as f:`
`for url in f.readlines():` and do whatever you want with each (URL)

Comment: @VictorSaraivaRocha, It works perfectly thank you :)
But, I have one issue, when I print the result it gives me only the result of last link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just work with each url:page *inside the loop*!

```py
    for line in f:
        url = line.strip()
        html = requests.get(url).text  # is .content better?
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        # work with soup here!
```

Creating more functions may help your program be easier to read if you find yourself packing a lot into some block
See [Cyclomatic Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) (which is practically a count of the control statements like `if` and `for`)

Additionally, if you want to collect up all the values before doing further processing (though this is frequently better accomplished with more esoteric logic like a generator or asyncio to collect many pages in parallel), you might consider creating some collection before the loop to store the results

```py
collected_results = []  # a new list
...
    for line in fh:
        result =  # process the line via whatever logic
        collected_results.append(result)

# now collected_results has the result from each line
```

Comment: thank you, but:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
NameError: name 'html' is not defined

Comment: @M.ZainAldin ah, I'd copied wrong from your block, it was just missing the assignment

Comment: It works perfectly thank you :)
But, I have one issue, when I print the result it gives me only the result of last link

Comment: whenever you use `=`, you're giving a name to the object returned from the right side; if you re-use the name, it'll have the most recent value! to collect many results, you likely want to put them all into some collection like a list (perhaps simply creating and naming a list before the loop and using `.append()` to push values into it as the loop goes)

Comment: I've added a second example about how to do just that

Comment: Thank you very much, I correct my mistake, I just put all the collected result inside the loop

Comment: Thank you, it's delightful idea. Instead of printing the results, I want to collect the results inside a text file

Answer (score 0):

you are making a big mistake by writing :

```
with open('F:\Python\Python-FilePy-Thesis-DownLoad/Thesis2.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        url = line.strip()

html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

because that will store the html data of the last url obtained from the TXT file in `html` variable.

after the for loop finish, the last line of the TXT file will be stored in variable `url` and that mean you will get only the last url in the TXT file

the code should be :

```
with open('F:\Python\Python-FilePy-Thesis-DownLoad/Thesis2.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        url = line.strip()
        html = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```